# What is the next item in the following sequence?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

11111111, 333333, 5555, 77, ?

Find the most complete and simplest solution that fits.

Comment: Whoever VTC'd did so for an incorrect reason.  In fact, I don't really see a reason to close this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most complete and simple solution I can think of

> is
>
>  the empty space above, represents
>  $ \mathbb{NOTHING} $
>
>  Factorising the numbers does not reveal any pattern so
>  I went with the sequence of digits. The next one after $1, 3, 5, 7$ is $9$.
>  The number of occurrences of each digit after $8, 6, 4, 2$ is $0$.
>  So there are no nines.
>  That is not zero, but an empty space — nothing.

Comment: I would be surprised if there were a simpler solution than this.

Comment: Empty nines, or empty anything, is there a difference?

Comment: @z100 oh yes. What is unsaid, can be as revealing as what is said. Consider too, that the absence of a winning lottery ticket is quite different from the absense of a losing lottery ticket.